# UWP APP : GetPublicKey() in Relase Config doesn't work

Tags: uwp

I built a UWP Project with the exe project and a class library project in which I'm reading the public key of the signed assembly with

`var assembly = typeof(MyClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
byte[] bytes = assembly.GetName().GetPublicKeyToken();`

That works well as long I'm using the debug configuration. After compiling and run in release mode, the bytes is null.
I unchecked the checkbox "Compile with .Net Native Toolchain" and now it works. I'm wondering why, and, do I have side effects because of that configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Native Toolchain will remove the metadata and we use the metadata to reflect the object.

If you need to use the reflection that you should add the code to the `Default.rd.xml` file.

```
<Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata">
  <Application>
           <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />
  </Application>
</Directives>
```

See [Runtime Directives (rd.xml) Configuration File Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/runtime-directives-rd-xml-configuration-file-reference)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/reflection-and-net-native

If you can read Chinese, please read my [blog](https://blog.lindexi.com/post/win10-uwp-%E5%8F%8D%E5%B0%84.html)